# Fizzbuzz in C++. printing each string prior to integer printing

Tags: c++, debugging, console, cout, fizzbuzz

Tried writing fizzbuzz out in C++, but prior to the console printing the list of integers it prints each string "Fizzbuzz, "fizz", "buzz"

Sample output:

```
   Fizzbuzz
   Fizz
   Buzz
   1
   2
   Fizz
   4
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
        if((i % 15) == 0)
                cout << "Fizzbuzz" << endl;
        if((i % 3) == 0)
                cout << "Fizz"<< endl;
        if((i % 5) == 0)
                    cout << "Buzz" << endl;
        else
            cout << i <<endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Missing some `else` before `if`.

Comment: YOU GO TO UH, DON'T YOU?!

Answer (score 2):

When checking for multiple conditions, for which only one branch should be taken, you need to use `else if`s after the first `if`. Then, the *first* branch for which the condition is met, will be taken:

```
    if((i % 15) == 0)
        cout << "Fizzbuzz" << endl;
    else if((i % 3) == 0)
        cout << "Fizz"<< endl;
    else if((i % 5) == 0)
        cout << "Buzz" << endl;
    else
        cout << i <<endl;
```

In your code, each condition gets checked, and each branch will be taken for which the condition is met. The `else` case in your code will be taken if the *last* `if` was not taken, i.e. it belongs to the last `if` only. When using `else if`, the `else` branch is taken if *none* of the conditions was met.